# Designing layouts for different orientations in VS blend - unwanted changes

Tags: layout, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, blend

Lately I've been designing some layout for a Windows Store app using Visual Studio 2013 with Blend. First I've prepared a full landscape view in Visual Studio edior, and then I've moved with it to Blend. I wanted to create another layout for another visual state, especially for a portrait view (when user rotates the tablet, for example). I thought I just need to turn the state recording on and drag elements as I will in the new VisualState, but when I changed grid's dimensions in PortraitView it also changed this grid's dimensions in LandscapeView (that I wanted to leave unchanged.) Is this a normal situation to happen?

I've tried reloading the file, even designing it from the start, but every time same effect - changing grid in one view results in changes in the same grid in other views. If this is how it should normally be, then is there a simple way to create a different view layout, using same objects but without changing the original layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears if the grid is not fixed size in any of the states, then changing it anywhere will have effects globally. But if we set the grid to be fixed size in one visual state, then changing its size in other states will only have effects localy (in the state where it was changed - desired behaviour.)